# On Mac OS X, why is firefox allocating memory, and not releasing it when its no longer needed?

Tags: mac, firefox, memory

I see this in other browsers, too, but I don't like those so I don't care.  Why does Firefox's memory usage (as shown in the Activity Monitor under "Memory" in the "Memory" tab) keep growing, even after closing tabs with pages I know tend to use more memory (e.g., Facebook), to the point where Firefox's performance becomes a spinning wheel after a simple mouse move, and other apps on my Mac suffer equally until I hit that little red button (Restart) or, if Firefox stops responding, use kill -9 or force close?  It appears to me that Firefox is dynamically allocating memory, but failing to release it when it's not needed anymore.

Just for what it's worth, I have seen the same issue with all plugins disabled, and I've seen it from Mac OS X Lion to High Sierra, on older and the latest version of Firefox that supports (most of) my plugins ... can't move to the newer versions until support is added back for those in newer versions.

My system is a Mac Mini with 8 GB of RAM using an Intel i7 dual core cpu.

This is not a rare problem...it's an everyday issue.  If Firefox's memory signature gets too huge (typically around 1.3 or 1.4 GB, it first stops responding, then simply crashes.

Right now, after a restart of Firefox, it's at 1 GB, about 300 MB larger than the OS kernel...but it WAS at 700 MB a few minutes ago.  When I close this tab, I expect it to go back to its previous 700 MB ... but it won't.

And, after reading a similar thread from 2015 (that did not answer the question I'm asking...or if it did, I didn't see that answer), I see people saying that even though that memory is allocated to Firefox but no longer in use BY Firefox, other apps (say, GIMP) can just as happily use that same memory if Firefox isn't using it, but is holding on to it.  Why then, doesn't that ever seem to work?  Why don't other apps and programs, like image editors (e.g., GIMP), get to release that memory from Firefox and claim it for their own use if that's how "modern operating systems" manage memory?

Again, I'm talking about memory that Firefox needs and dynamically allocates, uses, and then, when that need is gone, doesn't release it, not memory it's using at the time.  Firefox just gets bigger and bigger...until it either crashes on its own, I restart Firefox with the restart button in the plugins bar, or if it's not responding, have to resort to either kill -9 or force close from the Activity Monitor (which, I'm 99% sure is a GUI interface to kill -9).....